# PHP pthreads, classes aren't loaded inside the Thread instance and not set paremeters

Tags: php, facebook, multithreading, pthreads

I'm making use of pthreads to do to make through simultaneous publications of the Facebook API.

I created a scope and works well in a structured way, but with pthreads seems impossible to set the parameters of the API.

And when calling an instance of the API simply does nothing.

Can someone help me with this problem, what would be the most practical solution.

I have 2 files. A file is called by cron to run the process from time to time and do it to start processing threads.

```
<?php require_once("../../../Connections/sys_config.php"); // external functions
  require_once("../../inc/lib/facebook.php"); //include sdk
  require_once('cron.class.php'); // thread class

set_time_limit(0);
// API DATA
$appId     = 'XXXXXXXX'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = 'XXXXXXXX'; // Facebook App Secret

    //Call Facebook API
    // I instantiate the call to api facebook here because I can not do within the thread
try {
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => $appId,
          'secret' => $appSecret,
          'fileUpload' => true, 
          'cookie' => true,
));
} catch (Exception $e) {
   var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

    // Fetch the schedule according to the time set by the User
$fb_loadCronPostSYS = fb_loadCronPostSYS($time);
// with results continues
if($fb_loadCronPostSYS['totalReg'] > 0) {

// Create a array
$stack = array();
//Iniciate Multiple Thread
foreach ($fb_loadCronPostSYS['dados'] as $i) {
    $stack[] = new apiSEND($i, $facebook);
}
// Start The Threads
foreach ($stack as $t) {
    $t->start();
}
} else {
// does nothing 
} ?>
```

And here I run the thread. What actually as I can not set the access_token inside the thread I am not getting the data to the API had made publication.

```
<?php 
define("SQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("SQL_USER", "xxxx");
define("SQL_PASS", "xxxx");
define("SQL_DB",   "xxxx");

// I am using sql class to make calls to mysql
class sql {
public static $connection;

public static function __callstatic($method, $args){
    if (self::$connection) {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::$connection, $method), $args);
} else {
    self::$connection = new mysqli(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_DB);
    if (self::$connection)
    return call_user_func_array(array(self::$connection, $method), $args);
}
}
}

class apiSEND extends Thread {
public $data, $appId, $appSecret;

public function __construct($arg, $facebook) {
    $this->cad_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // $arg is array with the User data and publication that will be taken by the Facebook API
    $this->fb_loadCronPostSYS = $arg;  
    $this->user_id = $this->fb_loadCronPostSYS['fb_id'];
}

public function run() {
    if ($this->user_id) {
        printf("%s is Thread #%lu\n", __CLASS__, $this->getThreadId());

        // efetua a conexao com o access_token do BD, se precisar renova o access_token
        $accessToken = $this->fb_loadCronPostSYS['dados']['fb_access_token'];
        $this->facebook->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // pega os dados da api
            try {
              $fbuser = $this->facebook->getUser();
              $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me'); //user profile
              $user_permissions = $this->facebook->api("/me/permissions"); //list of user permissions
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
              error_log($e); 
              $fbuser = null;
            }
            echo 'fbuser:' . $fbuser;
            print_r($user_profile);
            print_r($user_permissions);

            // faz as publicacoes 
            if($fbuser) {
              // envia para API
              $post_msg = post_msg('message that will be posted', 'page that will be posted');
              sleep($tempo);
            }
        }


    }
} // fecha run
?>
```

Any help please.

How to instantiate clases within the thread? Or to set the parameters of an already instantiated class as is the case outside the thread that instantiates and passed as argument.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code that should help you to understand what is going on ...

```
<?php
class Bookface {
    protected $uid;

    public function __construct($uid) {
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    public function fetch() {
        return file_get_contents(
            "http://www.google.com/?q={$this->uid}");
    }

    public function getUID()        { return $this->uid; }
    public function setUID($uid)    { $this->uid = $uid; }
}

/* the same class again, safely ... */
class Safeface extends Stackable {
    protected $uid;

    public function __construct($uid) {
        $this->uid = $uid;
    }

    public function fetch() {
        return file_get_contents(
            "http://www.google.com/?q={$this->uid}");
    }

    public function getUID()        { return $this->uid; }
    public function setUID($uid)    { $this->uid = $uid; }
    public function run(){}
}

class Bookwork extends Thread {
    protected $bookface;
    protected $safeface;

    public function __construct(Bookface $bookface, Safeface $safeface) {
        $this->bookface = $bookface;
        $this->safeface = $safeface;
    }

    public function run() {
        var_dump(
            $this->bookface,
            $this->safeface);

        /*
         * This will not work, the object is not thread safe
         */
        $this->bookface->setUID(100);

        /*
         * This will work, the object is thread safe
         */
        $this->safeface->setUID(200);

        var_dump(
            $this->bookface,  /* this will be unchanged */
            $this->safeface); /* this will reflect changes */
    }
}

$faces = [new Bookface(1), new Safeface(2)];

$thread = new Bookwork($faces[0], $faces[1]);

$thread->start();
$thread->join();

/*
 * Changes made to safeface will be visible here
 */
var_dump($faces);
?>
```

Instantiating objects within the Thread is not a problem, the problem is that you are attempting to manipulate objects that are not thread safe from multiple contexts. The Facebook object is obviously not going to be thread safe, you can see from the example above that just descending from pthreads makes any objects of that class safe to use in multiple contexts, those objects then exhibit expected behaviour.

There are many examples on github, you should read them all.

Further reading: https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the reply.

But I'm having problems with Zend modules, this can give a check post in forum cPanel. Support staff cPanel is helping me, but too not find the problem and say I should seek support from Zend. What do you think? 

http://forums.cpanel.net/f442/how-install-php-pthreads-zts-387252.html

My username on the forum is the same as here. (sourceforge)